# Query optimization for table column update

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called Call_Data with about 850k records. I need to update a column but this query is taking a long time - about an hour.

Basically, select product_type from leads_file. If it is null then select product_type as HUA from Routing_Data, else select product_type from leads_file and update the product_type column in Call_data table with this value.

Thanks in advance!

```
update Call_Data set Call_Data.product_type = 
(select top 1 IIF([dbo].[leads_file].product_type = null, 
    (SELECT top 1 'HUA' as product_type from [dbo].[ROUTING_DATA], Call_Data calls where alt_id = calls.member_id), 
    (select top 1 [dbo].[leads_file].product_type FROM [dbo].[leads_file], Call_Data calls where alt_id = '00' + calls.member_id)
    )
    FROM [dbo].[leads_file], Call_Data calls where alt_id = '00' + calls.member_id)
where Call_Data.product_type is null
```

Comment: what is your questions?

Comment: I'm wondering why this update query is taking an hour plus to execute. There are less than a million rows in all tables concerned. I ran it initially and it took 7 mins. Subsequent runs are taking longer. I'm going to check if the table is locked...though I was able to stop this query execution and delete the rows of the table.

Comment: two of selects use a join on `alt_id = '00' + calls.member_id` and one uses a join on `alt_id = calls.member_id` -- should this be different or is that a typo?

Comment: That is normal.  It is how the member id is stored in those 2 separate tables. leads file has 00 + member id while routing data has the member id as is. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you cross joining `Call_Data` 3 times, that is where your issue is most likely to be? And you should use ANSI standard joins: `FROM [dbo].[leads_file] l JOIN Call_Data calls ON l.alt_id = '00' + calls.member_id`

Comment: So should I change it to: update Call_Data set Call_Data.product_type = 
(select top 1 IIF([dbo].[leads_file].product_type = null, 
    (SELECT top 1 'HUA' as product_type from [dbo].[ROUTING_DATA] RD JOIN Call_Data calls ON RD.alt_id = calls.member_id), 
    (select top 1 [dbo].[leads_file].product_type FROM [dbo].[leads_file] LF JOIN Call_Data calls ON LF.alt_id = '00' + calls.member_id)
    )
    FROM [dbo].[leads_file] LF JOIN Call_Data calls ON LF.alt_id = '00' + calls.member_id)
where Call_Data.product_type is null

Comment: I'm rerunning the query with the JOIN as suggested.  Been running for 10 mins. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Thanks all for the insights.  I used the JOINs as suggested.  The query ran in 30 mins, which is acceptable. I'll try optimizing it some more.

Comment: No, you should join `Call_Data` on the outside of the query if I'm following the logic correctly. Make sure you have indexing on all the join columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do -- but I'm not quite sure.

```
UPDATE Call_Data as CD
  set CD.product_type = 
  (
   SELECT TOP 1  COALESCE(lf_pt, 'HUA') as product_type
   FROM [dbo].[leads_file]
   where alt_id = '00' + CD.member_id
  )
WHERE CD.product_type  is null
```

---

In this example basetable has a value for index -- other tables may or may not have a record for index.

```
SELECT COALESCE(tab1.a, tab2.a, tab3.a, 'default') as "aValue"
FROM basetable
LEFT JOIN tab1 on tab1.index = basetable.index
LEFT JOIN tab2 on tab2.index = basetable.index
LEFT JOIN tab3 on tab3.index = basetable.index
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is wherever product type is NULL in Call_Data table, I need to check for the value in Leads File table. If that value is NULL, then I need to get the value from the Routing Data table, otherwise use the value from Leads File table.  Could you alter the query to include Routing Data?

Comment: @user1100221 -- you just left join to the other tables and then use coalesce to pick the right now... do you need to see an example of that?

Comment: Yes please.  Would appreciate that. The logic is: Select product type from leads_file table based on member id.  If it is null, then select product type from routing_data table based on member id and use that even if it is NULL; otherwise use the product type from leads file.  Update the product type column in the call_data table with this value.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1100221 -- ok I posted an example for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm trying this out right now.